# NuGet Package Manager Console Command Fails But Search -> Install Works

Tags: nuget

I was just installing a new package thats not in my local cache.  I took the command directly from the NuGet site.

Executing the command in the PMC failed with the following error:

```
The source at All [(Aggregate source)] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\Jammer\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Xam.Plugins.Settings'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Xam.Plugins.Settings
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I've confirmed all the settings are correct, all the usual NuGet source URLs are present and correct as expected.  I have NuGet 2.8.5 installed.

When I searched using the "Manage Packages for Solution" option within Visual Studio it found the package I was after and installed it all as expected.

Has anyone seen this and have an idea as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, OK>  Solved this immediately.

- I uninstalled the package from within the solution
- Removed the package from the NuGet local cache
- Then on the command line I did this
- cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet
- nuget.exe update -self

Turns out that the version of NuGet required for the package is stated as 2.8.1, the version in the cache was 2.8.3 so should have been fine but an update to 2.8.5 fixed the issue I was having with Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, although no C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet folder existed.
My version is 2.8.60318.667, I downloaded and installed it but I couldn't install any package.
The solution is in Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings.
Click on the Package Sources branch, and check 'nuget.org' as Available package sources.
Now it works fine.
Best Regards,

Comment: That is a different issue but glad you got it sorted.